# Quorum Vs Versioning, when should i use what?

Tags: versioning, distributed-computing, distributed, consensus, quorum

- A quorum is the majority number of servers that have to agree on a certain operation in order to move forward.
- Versioning is a counter for each record.

In a database, if latest version will always give me the latest and correct record.
When and why should i use Quorum for distributed systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quorum is required in a distributed environment where you are running a cluster of machines and anyone of these machines can accept a write/modify request and update the data.  Under such scenarios Quorum is used to identify the leader that will accept the writes or determine which node can accept write/modify requests for a given range of keys.

Let's consider a scenario where you have 3 master server accepting writes, in that case if you want to update the data, can we just match the version on one of the masters and assume it is safe to update?

No, because at the same moment some other write request to other master server  can also assume the same and hence you will end up with different state of data in different machines.

In this scenario, you need quorum to identify the leader that will accept writes for given range of data and then you can use versioning (optimistic locking) to ensure data is consistent across all machines and serialized.

Versioning, however is helpful when you have one master accepting the writes and multiple users might want try to update the data, using versioning here can help you to achieve Optimistic Locking. This is generally helpful when chances of locking are low.

Comment: Thanks, i thought we only have vector clocks and replicas syncing for brain-split problem.